# Filtering an association by missing records in Rails

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

In a Rails application I'm working on, I've got a few different models associated thusly (condensed for clarity):

`group.rb`

```
class Group < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :members, class_name: 'GroupMember'
  has_many :newsletters
end
```

`group_member.rb`

```
class GroupMember < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :group,

  has_many :subscriptions, inverse_of: :group_member, class_name: 'Newsletter::Subscriber'

  scope :subscribed_to, ->(newsletter_id) { joins(:subscriptions).merge(Newsletter::Subscriber.where(["newsletter_id = ?", newsletter_id])) }
  scope :not_subscribed_to, ->(newsletter_id) { where.missing(:subscriptions) }
end
```

`newsletter.rb`

```
class Newsletter < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_tenant :group

  has_many :subscribers, inverse_of: :newsletter
end
```

`newsletter/subscriber.rb`

```
class Newsletter::Subscriber < ApplicationRecord
  acts_as_tenant :group

  belongs_to :newsletter, inverse_of: :subscribers
  belongs_to :group_member, class_name: 'GroupMember', inverse_of: :subscriptions
end
```

Given the above associated models, here's the framework I'm working within:

- Each Group has *n* Group Members and *n* Newsletters.
- Each Group Member can have multiple Newsletter Subscriptions (one per newsletter in the group)

What I'm trying to do (unsuccessfully, so far), is find out which members in a group are NOT subscribed to a specific newsletter that is associated with the group.

I can find out the members that DO have a subscription using the following scope on the `GroupMember` object:

```
  scope :subscribed_to, ->(newsletter_id) { joins(:subscriptions).merge(Newsletter::Subscriber.where(["newsletter_id = ?", newsletter_id])) }
```

That allows me to query, for instance, `current_group.members.subscribed_to(current_group.newsletters.first.id)`.

However, I'm not sure how to negate that and get the the opposite of that set of members. That is, members NOT subscribed to that specific newsletter. The `:not_subscribed_to` scope I currently have defined isn't cutting it because it doesn't take into account which newsletter I'm referring to.

Comment: Why the <sql> tag? I see no SQL above. Do you expect a SQL answer?

Comment: @jarlh It’s true that I’m using active record here and not raw SQL. I suspect the answer will involve writing some raw SQL joins that I don’t fully understand yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the variable `newsletter_id`.

One alternative is to use `WHERE NOT EXISTS(...)` with a subquery:

```
Member
  .where(
    'NOT EXISTS(
       SELECT 1 FROM "subscriptions" 
       WHERE "subscriptions"."member_id" = "members"."id" 
       AND   "subscriptions"."newsletter_id" = ?
    )', newsletter_id
  )
```

Translated into Arel:

```
Member.where(
  Subscription.select('1')
              .where(
                Subscription.arel_table[:member_id].eq(Member.arel_table[:id])
              ).where(
                newsletter_id: newsletter_id
              ).arel.exists.not
)
```

Or group, count and having:

```
Member.group(:id)
      .left_joins(:subscriptions)
      .where(subscriptions: { newsletter_id: newsletter_id })
      .having(Subscription.arel_table[:id].count.eq(0))
```

Comment: Fantastic answer, Max! The LEFT OUTER join didn't work for me because (I think), it presupposes that the `subscriptions` table will have rows with `nil` `newsletter_id`s. However, the `WHERE NOT EXISTS` query makes a lot of sense for what I'm trying to do here. I utilized the Arel version of it in my scope, and it looks to be doing exactly what I need it to do. Thanks!

Comment: Hmm I'm slightly perplexed why the first one didn't work. Basically when you join and set a `WHERE subscription.member_id = NULL" you should get rows with no matches since you would get at least one match in the join table otherwise.

Comment: Well if I query that `WHERE` condition directly like so:
`Newsletter::Subscriber.where({ newsletter_id: newsletter_id, group_member_id: nil })`
I never get any rows back because `group_member_id` is never `nil`. In that case - correct me if I'm wrong - there's nothing to JOIN with the group members